# Using Traefik with multiple domains

Tags: traefik

I'm trying to setup dockerized version of traefik with two domains and certs generated with Let's Encrypt.

I've modified traefik.toml to look like this:

```
[acme]
  email = "email@example.com"
  storage = "acme.json"
  entryPoint = "https"
  OnHostRule = true

[[acme.domains]]
   main = "domain1.com"
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "domain2.com"
```

And in the docker-compose I've added these labels:

```
labels:
  - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:test-1.domain2.com"
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.port=80"
```

When I try to access a container on domain1.com with labels changes accordingly (frontend.rule), the cert is OK.

When I try to access a container on domain2.com though (test-1.domain2.com), the cert is self signed by traefik.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to setup both domains working with Let's Encrypt properly?

Comment: I'm in a similar situation trying to see why I get a self signed `883221dacd1d860cf85fdfe7bab3.456c20683ebfb7b0780025d8171.traefik.default` certificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, about the misleading information.  Due to my complex environmnet my previous test was not correct and my reply to your previous answer is not correct.

I **do** verify that switching to the `dnsChallenge` **does** generate and properly use a new certificate for the other domain.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

So, going through the logs showed:

```
traefik_1  | time="2018-02-15T13:15:35Z" level=debug msg="Look for provided certificate to validate [test-1.domain2.com]..."
traefik_1  | time="2018-02-15T13:15:35Z" level=debug msg="No provided certificate found for domains [test-1.domain2.com], get ACME certificate."
traefik_1  | time="2018-02-15T13:15:35Z" level=debug msg="Challenge GetCertificate test-1.domain2.com"
traefik_1  | time="2018-02-15T13:15:35Z" level=debug msg="ACME got nothing test-1.domain2.com"
```

and

```
traefik_1  | time="2018-02-15T13:14:58Z" level=debug msg="Loading ACME certificates [test-1.domain2.com]..."
traefik_1  | time="2018-02-15T13:14:59Z" level=error msg="map[test-1.domain2.com:[test-1.domain2.com] acme: Could not determine solvers]"
traefik_1  | time="2018-02-15T13:14:59Z" level=error msg="Error getting ACME certificates [test-1.domain2.com] : Cannot obtain certificates map[test-1.domain2.com:[test-1.domain2.com] acme: Could not determine solvers]+v"
```

Which lead me to https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/2018-01-09-issue-with-tls-sni-01-and-shared-hosting-infrastructure/49996, where you can read, that TLS-SNI-01 validation in Let’s Encrypt was disabled due to security concerns.

You can use DNS challange (https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#dnsprovider) should work (not tested it yet)

Comment: Good catch!  Unfortunately switching to `dnsChallenge` does **not** seem to fix my problem.  Let me know if you have better luck!

Comment: Hi - the link to the DNS challenge is broken. Do you mind sharing your updated traefik.toml file with DNS challenge? I've encountered a similar issue for my setup.

Comment: @mathee sure thing
https://gist.github.com/lubekpl/5fd05f33f65de8f3bb3bf18a34adfb16
this if for traefik v1 don't know if it will work properly for v2 :(